# Winforms how to select multiple check boxes inside mouse delimited area?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tab controls that I load images into it from xml file.
For each image in my xml file I create a table layout panel ant I fill it with some controls including a checkbox.
Is there a way to let the user mark an area with the mouse and have it check all the check boxes inside that area ?

Here is the code that generates the tables into the tab page:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xnList.Count; i++)
{
      PictureBox img = new PictureBox();
      //code to add image
      ...

      CheckBox chkSelectProduct = new CheckBox();
      chkSelectProduct.Text = "...";
      ...

      TableLayoutPanel tbl = new TableLayoutPanel();
      //adding the picturebox to the table
      //adding the checkbox to the table
```

[image: a screenshot]
          fileTab.controls.Add(tbl);
     }

At the end I have a tab control tab page with a lot of tables that each one contains a picture box and a checkbox.

Comment: You have to show code.  A TableLayoutPanel is not a replacement for a DataGridView.  It's unclear from your question what help you really need here.  Tag it c# of vb.net for a wider audience.

Comment: Do you mean "[How to select multiple controls by mouse-dragging over them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308906/how-to-select-multiple-controls-by-mouse-dragging-over-them)"?

Comment: You should make a UserControl that contains a PictureBox, a CheckBox and that label information.  Instead of a TableLayoutPanel, you should use a FlowLayoutPanel and just add the UserControl that you created to it.